# Why linked list is not inserting data when it is empty?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote this piece of code in C++ for the function Insert At Tail in a linked list but when the list is empty it is not inserting the data.

This is the picture of it:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKkXk.png

I don't know why the lines from 35 to 39 are not executed.

This is my code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;

    // Constructor
    node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

void display(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "The list is empty !!" << endl;
    }

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << "->";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Insert_At_Tail(node *head, int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new node(data);
        return;
    }

    node *tail = head;
    while (tail->next != NULL)
    {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = new node(data);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int data;
    cout << "Enter the data: ";
    cin >> data;
    Insert_At_Tail(head, data);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the snapshot of my output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFGj6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Insert_At_Tail(node *head, int data)
```

In C++, by default function parametes are passed ***by value***. This `head` parameter is a ***copy*** of the parameter that the caller passes in.

```
   head = new node(data);
```

This sets the new `head` pointer. This is fine, but because this `head` is a copy of the original parameter, this does absolutely nothing, whatsoever, to the caller's passed-in `head` pointer. All this does is set the function's `head` parameter/variable. This has no effect on the `head` that was passed into this function.

You can do one of two things (your choice):

1. Pass the parameter by reference
2. `return` the new value of the `head` pointer from this function (which could be unchanged from what was passed in, if there were no changes to the `head` pointer), and have the caller make save the new `head` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't change `head` at the caller. Either take a reference to the head

```
void insert_at_tail(node*& head, int data)
```

or better, return the new head:

```
void insert_at_tail(node *head, int data) {
    if (!head) return new node(data);
    node *tail = head;
    while (tail->next != NULL) tail = tail->next;
    tail->next = new node(data);
    return head;
}
```

called like such:

```
head = insert_at_tail(head, data);
```

Even better is to wrap the whole thing into a class so you can write `linked_list.insert_at_tail(data)` and only have to mutate its members.